# How to make 3 columns to the right for this view?

Tags: html, css

What I want to achieve is this view done with HTML and CSS:
[image]

I'm nearly done, all that is left is making the three columns to the right. My effort now gives this result:

[image]

The HTML that does this is

```
<div id="prio" class="yta2   TB_nb fontS80">
    <div class="fl50" id="L-col">
        <div class="clear half">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="fl25"><h3>Prioriteter</h3></div>
        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="fl20">Land/myndighet:</div>
        <div class="fl40"><input type="text" size="2">&nbsp;
                    <select name="">
                        <option value="1" SELECTED></option>
                        <option value="2"></option>
                        <option value="3"></option>
                        <option value="4"></option>
                        <option value="5">---------------------------------</option>
        </select></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="fl20">Prioritetens nummer:</div>
        <div class="fl40"><input type="text" value="<%= ansokanInfo.getPrionr() %>" name="<%= PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_PRIONR %>">&nbsp;<input type="button" value="S&ouml;k"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="fl20">Prioritetens ingivningsdag:<br>(Prioritetsdag)</div>
        <div class="fl40"><input type="text" size="10" name="<%=PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_PRIO_INGIVNINGSDAG%>" 
    id="<%=PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_PRIO_INGIVNINGSDAG%>" value="">&nbsp;<img src="images/cal.gif" width="16" height="15" alt="" onclick="javascript:openCalWin('620','300','<%=PandoraFieldConstants.FIELD_PRIO_INGIVNINGSDAG%>')"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="fl20">&nbsp;</div>

        <div class="fl45"><input type="checkbox" value="">Prioritetsdokument (bevis) finns tillsammans med &auml;rendet</div>
        <div class="clear lh10 bb fl80">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="clear half">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="fl20">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="fl20"><input type="button" value="Ta bort"></div>
        <div class="fl20"><input type="button" value="Avbryt">&nbsp;<input type="button" value="L&auml;gg till" onclick="javascript:doSubmitWithTarget('Grunduppgifter','addPrio','')"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fl50" id="R-col">
        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="fl95 hknot" style="height: 165px; overflow: auto;">
        <div class="fl20 pin"><strong>Prioritet</strong></div>

                <%
    for(int i = 0; i < ansokanInfo.getPrioriteter().size(); i++) { 
        Prioritet prio = ansokanInfo.getPrioriteter().get(i);
    %>
    <BR>prio<BR>
    <%
    }
    %>

            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--prio -->
```

My CSS file is

```
*  {font-family:arial;}

.avnamn{ 
                color: #90002b; 
                font-size: 140%; 
                display: inline; 
                vertical-align: 3%; 
                margin-left: 1%;
                }

.b{border:1px solid #000;}

.readonly{background-color: #CCC;}

.Webdings{
    font-family: Webdings;
    }

ul{margin-top: 0px}

.mt3{margin-top:-3px;}
.mt5p{margin-top:5px;}

.fontS80 {font-size: 80%;} 
a:link{color:#000; text-decoration:none; }
a:visited{color:#000; text-decoration:none; }
a:hover{color:#000; text-decoration:none; }
a:active{color:#000; text-decoration:none; }

.fontS75 {font-size: 75%;} 

.link{color: #003366;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;}

.link_sm{color: #003366;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;}

.link_sm{font-size: 70%;cursor: pointer;}

.small{font-size: 75%;}

.smallg{font-size: 75%;
color: #555;}

.ssmall{
    font-size: 65%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #555;
}
.small60{font-size: 60%;}
.small50{
    font-size: 50%;
    color: #333;
}
.smallb{font-size: 85%;}
table{display:inline;}

h1{font-size: 130%;display:inline;}
h2{font-size: 100%;display:inline;}
h3{
    font-size: 80%;
    display:inline;
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h4{font-size: 70%;display:inline;}
h5{
    font-size: 80%;
    display:inline;
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.hthin{
    font-size: 125%;
}

.th {text-align: left;}

td, th{font-size: 75%;
    vertical-align: text-top;}
.td_link{cursor: pointer;}
.td40{height:40px;}
.td60{height:60px;}



.thkant{
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 70%;
        text-align: left;
}

.labb{F0F0E3; c1c1b3 }

.bb{border-bottom: 1px solid #000;}
.bbV{border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;}
.TB_nbA {background-color:#CCC;}
.TB_bt, .TB_nb, .TB_db, .TB_bb {background-color:#efefdc;}

.hk {background-color:#d9ddb3;}

.hknot {background-color:#f9faf2;}
/*<!--F8F8F1-->*/
.TB_bt{border-top: 1px solid #FFF;}
.TB_bt5{border-top: 5px solid #FFF;}
.TB_bb{border-bottom: 1px solid #999;}
.TB_bb2{border-bottom: 2px solid #c1c1b3;}
.TB_db{border-bottom: 1px solid #000; border-top: 1px solid #000;}
.TB_tb{border-top: 2px solid #efefdc;}

.TB_bo{border: 2px solid #efefdc;}
.TB_bo_hk{border-top: 1px solid #efefdc;}


.TB_bo2{border: 1px solid #efefdc;}

.TB_bo2B{
border-top: 2px solid #c1c1b3;
border-left: 3px solid #efefdc;
border-right: 3px solid #efefdc;
border-bottom: 2px solid #c1c1b3;
}

.TD_bo{
    border-right: 1px solid #c1c1b3;
    width: 9%;
    font-size: 70%;
    text-align: center;
}

.TD_bo2{

    border-right: 0;
    width: 9%;
    font-size: 70%;
    text-align: center;
}

.ytb{
    border-left:3px solid #efefdc;
    border-right:3px solid #efefdc;
}

.datum {
    font-size: 70%;
    padding-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: text-top;} 
.sub {background:#EAEAEA;}
.sub_meny, .sub_meny_r, .sub_meny_active, .sub_meny_sm{
    font-size: 70%;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: text-top;}

.sub_meny_sm {
    font-size: 60%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}   

.sub_meny_r{
    float:right;
    font-size: 70%;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;}

.sub_meny_rm{margin-top:4px;}
.sub_meny_active{font-weight: bold;}

.flikkant1 {
    background-image: url(../images/fl1k.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    z-index: -1;}

.inl_namn{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 70%;
    color: Black;
    text-decoration: none;}

.th{text-align: left;}
.tr{text-align: right;}

.g1{
    background-color: #FFF;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.g2{
    background-color: #EEE;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.g3{
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 100%;
}
.g4{
    background-color: #CCC;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.popup{
    border-color: #000; 
    border-style: groove; 
    border-width: 2px; 
    padding: 0px; 
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-size: 70%;
}

.popupN{
    background-color: #F0F0E3;
    color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.pin{padding: 6px;}

.fl10, .fl20, .fl30, .fl40, .fl50, .fl60, .fl70, .fl80, .fl90, .fl100 {
    padding-bottom:4px;color: #000000;
}

.over{
    background-color: #EFEFDC;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.half{
line-height:50%;
}

.quarter{
line-height:25%;
}

.lh10{
line-height:10%;
}

.checkmargin {margin-right: 25px;}  
.checkmarginL {margin-left: 25px;}  

.pusher {padding-left: 15px;"}
.pusherR {margin-right: 40px;"}

.rand3{background-color: #FFF; line-height: 3px;}
.rand1{background-color: #FFF; line-height: 1px;}

.whiteborder {     color: #ffffff;      border: 4px solid #ffffff;      padding: 10px;      margin: 10px; }
#details { width: 580; color: #ffffff; }
.column1 {     color: #000000; margin: 0;      padding: 0;     width: 500px;     border:0;     float: left; }
.example_column2 {     color: #000000;margin: 0;      padding: 0;     border:0;     width: 80px;     float: right; }

.f200 {
    color: #000000;
}

.f210 {
    color: #000000;float: left;
}
```

What can be done to achieve the view?

Thanks

### Update

I updated the view with an HTML table and the result is not so bad:
[image]

The HTML I used is

```
<BR><table><tr><td><b>Prioritet</b></td><td><b>Prioritetsdag</b></td><td><b>Prio.dok i ärende</b></td></tr>
            <%
for(int i = 0; i < ansokanInfo.getPrioriteter().size(); i++) { 
    Prioritet prio = ansokanInfo.getPrioriteter().get(i);
%>
<tr><td>
<%= prio.getLand() %></td><td> <%= prio.getNr() %></td><td><%= prio.getNr() %></td></tr> <BR>
<%
}
%></table>
```

Comment: your code is actually unclean and full of empty elements you should strongly avoid. You should try to focus first to the main structure with a form and a table floated side by side and then add style to the nested elements

Comment: Did you try with an html table? Can you share a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your code?

Comment: I tried it with an HTML table and the result is quite good. I updated the original question with the HTML table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even so creating layouts in html using table tags is not a good idea, creating a table using div tags is not a good idea, too ;) Use a table tag and iterate the rows with your loop.

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer. I ended up doing it with an HTML table.